# Заполнение одной таблицы на основе другой с заполнением таблицы отношений

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблицы

```
T1(Id INT, ...)

T2(Id INT, ...)
```

В таблице Т1 есть начальные данные. На основе них создаются данные в таблице Т2 (1 к 1). Но обратного сопоставления нет, поэтому есть еще третья таблица

```
T3(T1Id INT, T2Id INT)
```

И вот тут встает вопрос о том, как заполнить таблицу Т2 из таблицы Т1 чтобы одновременно внести соответствия в таблицу Т3. Таблица Т3 изначально заполнена идентификаторами из Т1.

Хотелось бы что то типа

```
UPDATE T3 SET T2Id = it.Id
FROM (INSERT INTO T2 (somedata) OUTPUT INSERTED.Id .............) it
```

Но это не работает. Инструкция INSERT хоть и возвращает табличные данные, но как таблицу ее использовать нельзя.

Кроме курсора ничего в голову не приходит, но не хочу я его использовать

Comment: может что то типа `output ... into @временная_таблица_в_памяти` `update ... from @временная_таблица`. правда я не понимаю как вы id свяжете, output ведь только id из t2 вернет, как вы их с t1 свяжете ...

Comment: @Mike, вот и я не понимаю как. Поэтому работаю с перебором курсором... А хотелось бы красоты.

Comment: @Mike, ну чисто логически, если я создаю одни данные на основе других, то у меня должна быть возможность в этот момент иметь как стартовые данные, так и конечные, причем сопоставленные. В реалиях ООП это тривиальная задача. А вот с SQL беда прям.

Comment: Кстати, используются identity id или можно взять другой способ формирования ? В случае использования sequence можно было бы сначала дать update, а после него insert, что сразу становится тривиальной задачей.

Comment: И вы кстати можете взять `merge`, предложенный @i-one выполнить into в временную таблицу и на основе нее сделать update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Таблица Т3 изначально заполнена идентификаторами из Т1.

Если бы не это, можно было бы за раз заполнить T2 и T3 из T1 с помощью `MERGE`.

Пример:

```
create table T1 (id int, a int);
create table T2 (id int, b int);
create table T3 (id1 int, id2 int);

insert into T1 values (1, 100), (2, 200);

merge into T2 t
using T1 s
on 1 = 0
when not matched then
    insert (id, b)
    values (s.id + 20, 10 * s.a)
output s.id, inserted.id into T3 (id1, id2);

select * from T2;
select * from T3;

drop table T1;
drop table T2;
drop table T3;
```

Comment: В общем то я придумал как это прикрутить к моей задаче. Спасибо тебе, человек!